# GFCI Bathroom Outlet Open Hot

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, receptacle, circuit-breaker, gfci

For some reason the outlet keeps tripping the breaker. There are 2 other outlets on this breaker as far as now, one of the front and back porch. This is the bathroom wiring. Any help? Should I pull the other two outlets are post pictures?]

[image: [enter image description here][1]For some reason the outlet keeps tripping the breaker. There are 2 other outlets on this breaker as far as now, one of the front and back porch. This is the bathroom wiring. Any help? Should I pull the other two outlets are post pictures?]

Comment: Let me clarify it is not tripping the breaker, it is just showing open hot in all three outlets associated with that breaker. I assume it has to do with this GFCI in the bathroom, it’s been an issue before.

Comment: Has that GFCI been replaced before?  Are those wires just push-in or screwed tighten?  Simple push-ins have a bad name.

Comment: It has been replaced it looks like at some point during a remodel, it’s a screw tighten.

Comment: Would check the other two, outside does tend to be harder.  Open hot on those three light plug ins don't tell much more than it is not working.  A multi meter will give better information.

Comment: Pull out all the receptacles,  like the picture but don't disconnect any wires. Turn on the breaker. Use a non contact voltage tester to carefully check the wires. If the blacks show hot then you've likely got GFCIs that aren't resetting. If nothing shows hot then you've got a problem at the breaker or somewhere between breaker and first receptacle.

Comment: Almost all the indications of those 3-light testers are flat wrong.  "Open hot" just means "there is no power here" and it isn't any more conclusive than that.  Other readings are *extremely misleading*.  They are not made to identify wiring failures in old wiring that worked before!  They only made to detect wiring mistakes in brand new wiring.

Comment: Are you sure you have identified **all** the devices and receptacles on the circuit?  Is anything plugged into any of the other outlets?  Since they're outside can you open up the box and have a look?  By the way the GFCI wiring looks correct.